# How To Play Sound on Android Firemonkey

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I have the following code:

```
uses
  MMSystem;

procedure TForm3.AddSound;
var
  hFind, hRes: THandle;
  Song: PChar;
begin
  hFind := FindResource(HInstance, 'Resource_1', RT_RCDATA);
  if hFind <> 0 then begin
    hRes:=LoadResource(HInstance, hFind);
    if hRes <> 0 then begin
      Song:=LockResource(hRes);
      if Assigned(Song) then SndPlaySound(Song, snd_ASync or snd_Memory);
      UnlockResource(hRes);
    end;
    FreeResource(hFind);
  end;
end;
```

It works fine in Windows when calling this procedure in the `OnClick` event of a button, but the same code is not working for Android. I get the following error:

> [DCC Fatal Error] Unit3.pas(8): F2613 Unit 'MMSystem' not found.

Answer (score 1):

This code doesn't work on Android because `MMSystem` is not a cross-platform unit in the FireMonkey library.  It is a Windows-only unit in the VCL library instead.  Mobile projects must use FireMonkey only, not VCL.

To play sounds on Android, look at FireMonkey's [`TMediaPlayer`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Media.TMediaPlayer) component.  However, it cannot play audio from resources, so you will have to deploy the audio file along side your app and play it from file instead.

See Embarcadero's [Audio-Video in FireMonkey](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Audio-Video_in_FireMonkey) documentation for more details.

Comment: Any other option or way is there to play from resource. Thanks.